# create a collection of all possible objects states

Tags: c#

I have a chain of five objects. Each object has a State which can be True or False. 
I need to create a Collection or Dictionary of all possible chains , depends on object state individually. 
For example :

```
        Value             Key
obj1 obj2 obj3 obj4 obj5  00000   //obj1=false obj2=false obj3=false obj4=false obj5=false
obj1 obj2 obj3 obj4 obj5  00001   //obj1=false obj2=false obj3=false obj4=false obj5=true
obj1 obj2 obj3 obj4 obj5  ..... 
obj1 obj2 obj3 obj4 obj5  11111   //obj1=true obj2=true obj3=true obj4=true obj5=true
```

How to do it in a proper and elegant  way ?

let say each object has type of

```
class Unit
{
    public bool State {get;set;}
}
```

the chain is

```
class Chain
{
    public Unit obj1 {get;set;}
    public Unit obj2 {get;set;}
    public Unit obj3 {get;set;}
    public Unit obj4 {get;set;}
    public Unit obj5 {get;set;}
}
```

The dictionary item should be : Chain as Value and 10101 as a Key

Comment: Your key resembles the binary interpretation of numbers between `0` and `31`. But I actually don't understand what a "chain of objects" is.

Comment: @Groo thanks , but how to fill and create a collection base on this information ?

Comment: @Z.R.T.: what is a chain of objects? What do these objects represent? Are you talking about `bool`s? Leave the implementation aside for a moment and try to explain exactly what you are trying to do.

Comment: what is a chain of 5 objects?

Comment: What is going to be inside of that collection or dictionary? `bool` values? You don't need those, just use `byte` to store state (`enum` is better choice if you want to give a name to individual object and access their value by that name, where value is `true` for `1` and `false` for `0`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using *Linq*: we want a `Range` of `0..31` materialized as a `Dictionary`. The only (possible) diffculty is a *bits manipulation*:

- To compute `2**n` (`2**5 == 32` in our case) for the *range* we can shift `1` at `n` positions to the left, in our case: `1 << 5 == 0b10000 == 32`
- To check if `k`-th bit is set we can use `value >> k & 1 != 0`:

A little picture on what's going on

```
      011...0101...1 : value
             ^
             k-th bit
```

After shifting *right* (`value >> k`):

```
            011...01 
                   ^
                   former k-th bit is now the 1st one (`01...1` part's gone)

            011...01 after bitwise & 1
                   1
            --------   
                   1 either 1 or 0 (depending on if k-th bit set or not)
```

**Code:**

```
  using System.Linq;

  ...

  var demo = Enumerable
    .Range(0, 1 << 5)
    .ToDictionary(key => key,
                  key => new {
                    //TODO: put right object here instead the anonymous one
                    obj1 = (key >> 4 & 1) != 0,
                    obj2 = (key >> 3 & 1) != 0,
                    obj3 = (key >> 2 & 1) != 0,
                    obj4 = (key >> 1 & 1) != 0,
                    obj5 = (key >> 0 & 1) != 0,
                  });

   Console.Write(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, demo));
```

**Outcome:**

```
   [0, { obj1 = False, obj2 = False, obj3 = False, obj4 = False, obj5 = False }]
   [1, { obj1 = False, obj2 = False, obj3 = False, obj4 = False, obj5 = True }]
   [2, { obj1 = False, obj2 = False, obj3 = False, obj4 = True, obj5 = False }]
    ...
   [29, { obj1 = True, obj2 = True, obj3 = True, obj4 = False, obj5 = True }]
   [30, { obj1 = True, obj2 = True, obj3 = True, obj4 = True, obj5 = False }]
   [31, { obj1 = True, obj2 = True, obj3 = True, obj4 = True, obj5 = True }]
```

Comment: For sake of completeness for the readers try explaining the bit manipulation logic.

Comment: @Kunal Mukherjee: Thank you! Bitwise logics may well want explanations. I've edited the answer

Answer (score 1):

Lets say 00000 = 0 and 11111 = 31 like binary data

```
List<string> result = new List<string>();

for(int i=0;i<32;i++)
{
   result.Add(Convert.ToString(i, 2).PadLeft('5','0'));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It would probably make more sense to keep a list of units, instead of having a separate property for each item, i.e.

```
class Chain
{
    readonly List<Unit> _units;
    public IReadOnlyList<Unit> Units => _units;

    public string Key => string.Concat(_units.Select(u => u.State ? "1" : "0"));

    public Chain(params bool[] units)
    {
        _units = units.Select(u => new Unit { State = u }).ToList();
    }
}
```

Then if you create a "chain":

```
var chain = new Chain(true, false, false, true, false);
```

you get its key using `chain.Key`.